# Find last occurrence of period with regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex for validating URLs. I know there are many advanced ones out there, but I want to create my own for learning purposes.

So far I have a regex that works quite well, however I want to improve the validation for the TLD part of the URI because I feel it's not quite there yet.

Here's my regex (or find it on [regexr](http://regexr.com/3dgo3)):

```
/^[(http(s)?):\/\/(www\.)?a-zA-Z0-9@:._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}\b([/#?]{0,1}([A-Za-z0-9-._~:?#[\]@!$&''()*+,;=]|(%[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}))*)$/
```

It works well for links such as `foo.com` or `http://foo.com` or `foo.co.uk`

The problem appears when you introduce subdomains or second-level domains such as `co.uk` because the regex will accept `foo.co.u` or `foo.co.`.

I did try using the following to select the substring after the last `.`:

```
/[(http(s)?):\/\/(www\.)?a-zA-Z0-9@:._\+~#=]{2,256}[^.]{2,}$/
```

but this prevents me from defining the `path` rules of the URI.

How can I ensure that the substring after the last `.` but before the first `/`, `?` or `#` is at least 2 characters long?

Comment: If you want to learn, why are you asking us? Take one of the advanced and analyze it. ;)

Comment: How about just testing for `\.\w{2,}$`? It'll check that it ends with at least 2 characters after the last `.`.

Comment: @ClasG The advanced ones are thousands of characters long. :) Your regex doesn't quite work if you have path in the url (e.g `foo.co.uk/test?id=1`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, you're almost there. Made some modification and it seems to work.

```
^(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9@:._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}([/#?;]([A-Za-z0-9-._~:?#[\]@!$&''()*+,;=]|(%[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}))*)?$
```

Can be somewhat shortened by doing

```
^(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?[\w@:.\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}([/#?;]([-\w.~:?#[\]@!$&''()*+,;=]|(%[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}))*)?$
```

(basically just tweaked your regex)

The main difference is that the *parameter part* is optional, but if it is there it has to start with one of `/#?;`. That part could probably be simplified as well.

[Check it out here](http://regexr.com/3dgof).

**Edit:**

After some experimenting I think this one is about as simple it'll get:

```
^(http(?:s)?:\/\/)?([-.~\w]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})(:\d+)?(\/[-.~\w]*)?([@/#?;].*)?$
```

It also captures the separate parts - scheme, host, port, path and query/params.

[Example here](http://regexr.com/3dgp7).

Comment: I think you might even do fine with this one: `^(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?[\w@:.\+~=]{2,256}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}\/?([#?;].*)?$`. It allow anything after an optional *URL-terminator*.

Comment: Doesn't allow path it seems, e.g: `foo.com/path`

Comment: This might be a better one - handles port as well `^(http(?:s)?:\/\/)?((?:www\.)?[-.~\w]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})(:\d+)?(\/[-.~\w]*)?([@/#?;].*)?$`. [Check it out here](http://regexr.com/3dgor). It captures five parts separately - scheme, host, port, path and query/params.

Comment: Nice! Seems to work really well. Perhaps you should update your answer and add that one too?